# Pulling text not enclosed in tags from a webpage

Tags: php, regex, domdocument

I'm trying to crawl web pages and pull text from them using DOMDocument in PHP. Unfortunately, the HTML is difficult to work with. For example, it looks something like this:

```
<p class="thisClass">
    <a href="/a/link">Link</a>
    <br>
    The text I need: 0613
    <br>
</p>
```

I'm not sure how to pull out "The  text I need: 0613", since it's not enclosed in its own tag. Would regex be the best way to pull this out? I know that the format of the line will always be "The text I need: " followed by a four digit number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `I know that the format of the line will always be "The text I need: " followed by a four digit number.`

In that case you can probably use:

```
preg_match('/The text I need:\s*(\d+)/i', $str, $matches);
```

Your required number will be available in `$matches[1]`.

**PS:** However for reliably parsing HTML page use DOM parsers.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is this likely the most efficient way to get the text in this case?

Comment: If you know the prefix string before number then yes this will work fine.

Comment: Great, thanks! To address your PS, what's the advantage of using a DOM parser?

Comment: SInce HTML is not very regular language and if you are scrapping content from HTML then php's DOM parser provides your reliable APIs to extract various content using xpath, xquery etc.